# JPS not showing hbase or hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-whirr

I set up a hbase/hadoop cluster on ec2 using Apache Whirr but when I ssh into the namenode (hbase master) and run `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps` all I see running is jps, no mention of hbase or namenode. They are running, however, because I was able to work with both of them. Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jps` displays java processes for the current user, and sometimes only sessions it can resolve to the current user (so doesn't always work as expected).

Try a `ps axww | grep java` instead, that should list the java executables running, with full command line arguments

Comment: Right again Chris. The output obviously isn't as clean as with jps but at least it serves as a sanity check to see the various components running! Thanks